# Continuity of specific bivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be defined by the argument-value description:
$$f(x, y) = (x+1)^y $$
then I should be able to show that $f$ is continuous on the unit square $[0,1]^2$.

However, so far, I did not manage to do it. I tried using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition but it becomes very difficult very quickly. Therefore, I would like to ask if there is any easier way of showing it.

---

As always any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: You can use $(x+1)^y=e^{y\ln{(x+1)}}$, and then by properties that the product of continuous functions is continuous and that composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @Koncopd What kind of composition were you thinking of?

Comment: $g(z)=e^z,\ h(x,y)=y,\ p(x,y)=\ln{(x+1)}$ and $f(x,y)=g(h(x,y)\cdot p(x,y))$.

Comment: @Koncopd Thank you very much for your brilliant answer!

Comment: thx, moved to the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from the comments.

You can use represent $f(x,y)=(x+1)^y=e^{y\ln{(x+1)}}$ and use the properties of continuous functions: the product of continuous functions is continuous and the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Then, taking $g(z)=e^z$ continuous, $h(x,y)=y$ continuous and $p(x,y)=\ln{(x+1)}$ continuous, represent $f(x,y)$ as the product and composition
$$f(x,y)=g(h(x,y)\cdot p(x,y))$$